# What portable light dimmer to use for cieling lights?

Tags: light-fixture

I'm throwing a party and I can't go and change all of the light switches because the house is already finished. But I want to be able to dim the lights; is there a portable light dimmer that will work on ceiling lights without me having to go and re-due the electrical work?

Comment: Replacing light switches with dimmers is (typically) a simple task and does not involve redoing any electrical work. Just swap out the switch for a dimmer. Cost should be much less than smart bulbs, too.

Comment: As much as I would love to replace the switched with dimmers my parents said no to that so I'm trying to find another way around replacing anything

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Philips Hue and competitors.  They are smart bulbs you control with your smartphone and possibly a hub you put at a receptacle.  They screw right in, no fuss, no bother.